# Django: make field editable depending on the value of other field

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django, and I haven't found the answer yet in the extensive documentation. I'm asking for pointers to research, not for working code. That being said, here's my problem:

In one of my models theres a BooleanField (it gets rendered in the admin form as a checkBox). Let's call it 'A'. It only makes sense to edit other field (say, CharField 'B') if A is checked.

So, is there a way to make B read only, or even changing its content to an empty string, dinamically, if A is checked? Thank you.

(Django 1.5.2, Python 2.7.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need several things to make this work. You may be able to skip some of them depending if you mainly care abut the UI, or the data integrity in the db.

Since the user can (presumably) check/uncheck Field A on the client-side you need some Javascript to enable/disable the appearance of Field B. These docs show how to load custom JS in your ModelAdmin class:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions

In your ModelForm you may want to do some check in the `__init__` method against the value of `self.instance.field_a` and substitute some kind of [ReadOnlyWidget](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1682/) for Field B for the initial display of the form. These docs show how to give your ModelAdmin a custom form class:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form
If you are writing some Javascript to do that dynamically it make be easier to skip this step and just do it client-side.

Finally you can use Django model validation to ensure that Field B is saved with a null value if Field A is checked:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects