# Django - Restrict a drop down options depending on another drop down

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu

I have 2 drop downs.

First drop down asks for the type.

I have a second drop down that shows values from another Model.

What I need is that, if the first drop down as a type: qualif, I only want to show the pk=1 of the second drop down.

This is what I have so far:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=40,verbose_name="nom")
type = models.CharField(max_length=6,choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
division = models.ForeignKey(Division,verbose_name="division")

 class TournamentForm(forms.ModelForm):

def clean(self):
    super(TournamentForm, self).clean() #if necessary
    if 'division' in self._errors:
        """     
            reset the value (something like this i 
            think to set the value b/c it doesnt get set 
            b/c the field fails validation initially)
        """
        if self.data['type'] == 'qualif':
            division = Division.objects.get(pk=1)
            self.division = division

        # remove the error
        del self._errors['division']

    return self.cleaned_data

  # Register your models here.
     class TournamentAdmin(reversion.VersionAdmin):
form = TournamentForm
list_display = ('name', 'date', 'division', 'gender')
ordering = ('date', 'name')
list_filter = ['date', 'season', 'division', 'gender']

    admin.site.register(Tournament, TournamentAdmin)
```

I read from another stack question to use clean...but sadly it's not working...

EDIT:
After looking at @Mardo's link, I tried loading up a static file.

Here is my folder setup:

myproject/static/admin/js/myfile.js

And this in my settings.py

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

But it keeps saying file not found...

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: Probably simpler to do client-side.  Send all possible values to the web page along with some kind of mapping, and then use javascript or jquery to re-populate the 2nd dropdown when the 1st dropdown changed.

Comment: I posted a similar question a few days ago. I was looking for a 'concetptual' kind of answer, a guide to understand the posibilities of django regarding these kind of stuff. The answer was very clear, I'think it will help you too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753810/django-make-field-editable-depending-on-the-value-of-other-field

Comment: @Marcos Modenesi, Thanks! I have a problem loading the asset file tho... I edited my first post to show the folder setup.

Comment: Look at the source code of the page to see what url is finally recieving the file you want to load and if it matches myproject/static/admin/js/myfile.js

Comment: This is the url that it's trying to load: http://localhost:8000/static/admin/js/myfile.js

Comment: I managed to fix it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make two forms. First have only first dropdown, second is disabled. On selecting value commit form and render full version based on first.